# Select only certain columns from the data frame in R

Tags: r, lapply

I am novice in R. I have a below dataframe from which I need to select particular columns.

Dataframe looks like below:

```
df<-data.frame(city=as.character("Boston","Boston","Boston","Boston","Boston","Boston","Boston","Boston","Boston","Boston"),
              a.Boston=c(rep(8,3),rep(6,4),9,5,7),
              a.Hartford=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              a.Denver=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_0=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_1=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_2=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_3=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_4=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_5=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_6=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_7=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_8=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_9=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_10=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_11=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Boston_12=c(rep(8,3),rep(9,4),3,8,9),
              b.Denver_0=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_1=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_2=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_3=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_4=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_5=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_6=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_7=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_8=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_9=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_10=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_11=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0),
              b.Denver_12=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,4),1,5,0))
```

I want to create dataframe df1 to df12 based on the selection of columns. For example df2 should not contains columns which has suffix "_1" in 
their name, but contains rest of the columns. For df9, should not contain columns which has "_1","_2",... upto "_8"
such as b.Boston_1,b.Denver_1,b.Boston_2,b.Denver_2.....b.Boston_8,b.Denver_8 but contains columns such as
b.Boston_10,b.Denver_10,b.Boston_11,b.Denver_11. And df12 would contain only columns such as a.Boston,a.Hartford,a.Denver.
And I want to remove "city" column from the df's.

I have written below code:

```
i1 <- 0:12
for(i in seq_along(i1)) {
  assign(paste0("df", i),
         value = df[, setdiff(names(df),
                                  c("city", 
                                    grep(paste("_", 0:i1[i],collapse="|", sep=""),
                                         colnames(df), value = TRUE)))])
}
```

Below I got the result:

```
*df2*

      a.Boston a.Hartford a.Denver b.Boston_2 b.Boston_3 b.Boston_4 b.Boston_5 b.Boston_6 b.Boston_7 b.Boston_8
1        8          6        8          8          8          8          8          8          8          8
2        8          6        8          8          8          8          8          8          8          8
  b.Boston_9 b.Denver_2 b.Denver_3 b.Denver_4 b.Denver_5 b.Denver_6 b.Denver_7 b.Denver_8 b.Denver_9
1          8          6          6          6          6          6          6          6          6
2          8          6          6          6          6          6          6          6          6
```

*df9*:

```
 a.Boston a.Hartford a.Denver b.Boston_9 b.Denver_9
1        8          6        8          8          6
2        8          6        8          8          6
```

Problem, with the created dataframes is, say for df2 and df9 is they are not containing columns from b.Denver_10 to b.Denver_12
and b.Boston_10 to b.Boston_12. None of the dataframes from df1 to df11 contains the columns having suffix _10,_11,_12 but it should be there instead.

Desired o/p:

*df9*:

```
a.Boston a.Hartford a.Denver b.Boston_9 b.Boston_10 b.Boston_11 b.Boston_12 b.Denver_9 b.Denver_10
1        8          6        8          8           8           8           8          6           6
2        8          6        8          8           8           8           8          6           6
  b.Denver_11 b.Denver_12
1           6           6
2           6           6
```

*df10*:

```
a.Boston a.Hartford a.Denver b.Boston_10 b.Boston_11 b.Boston_12 b.Denver_10 b.Denver_11 b.Denver_12
1        8          6        8           8           8           8           6           6           6
2        8          6        8           8           8           8           6           6           6
```

This type of o/p, I want from df1 to df12.

Can anyone could help me with this?

Thank in advance!!

Comment: @loki, both the questions are different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply(1:12, function(k)
{
    # match numbers equal or greater than k in colnames of df
    pattern <- if (k < 10) paste0("\\..*\\D$|_([",k,"-9]|1[0-2])$") else 
        paste0("\\..*\\D$|_(1[",k%%10,"-2])$")
    df[,grepl(pattern, colnames(df))]
})
```

Edit: Inside the `lapply`, I first define a regex patern that matches desired columns. I.e.

A) the columns that contain a '.' and do not contain a number followed by line end. `(\\..*\\D$)` This matches the column with format `a.CityName`

B) the columns that contain a '_' followed by number equal or larger than given `k` and not larger than 12. The formula depends on whether k<10. E.g. for k = 2, we get `_([2-9]|1[0-2])$` - match 2 to 9 or 1 followed by 0 to 2. For k = 11 we get `_(1[1-2])$`.

Then I select the columns  that match the pattern with grepl.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The code is a lot clearer if we specify conditions for the columns we want rather than constructing regex.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

column_suffixes <- str_extract(names(df), '\\d+') %>%
    as.integer

lapply(seq_len(12), function(i) {
    df %>%
        select_if(is.na(column_suffixes) | column_suffixes >= i) %>%
        select(-city)
})
```

`column_suffixes` is just a vector integers from the column names. This will be `NA` if there is no integer.

`select_if` just subsets the columns of `df` where the suffix is missing or `>= i`. This has the same effect as

```
df[, is.na(column_suffixes) | column_suffixes >= i]
```

Comment: ,I have one more question, I need to remove columns such as a.Boston, a.Hartford depending on city name. For example, if city value is Boston, drop column a.Boston, if it is Hartford drop column a.Hartford. Because my original data frame contains many city values.